# How to get dot files to show in networking sharing?

Tags: release-hera

I'm using Elementary OS Hera, I got a new computer that I'm trying to transfer the data to. I enabled SAMBA, but whenever I connect to my computer from my new one it only shows /home/chris it doesn't show files like .mozilla or .steam which are in my home directory. This is what I have in smb.conf

```
[sharingtime]
  comment = My Folders
  read only = no
  path = /home
  browsable = yes
  guest ok = yes
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have samba user assigned to your shared directory, Make sure you create samba user first like below:

```
smbpasswd -a chris
smbpasswd -e chris
```

You've to add your samba user to a shared folder like below

```
[sharingtime]
comment = My Folders
path = /home
valid users = chris
browseable = yes
guest ok = no
writeable = yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually press ctrl+h each time to show hidden files.

Eventually add to each samba share entry in samba.cfg something like that:

```
inherit acls = Yes
create mask = 660
directory mask = 770
```